# Entity Framework 5 does not clear navigation property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-5

I've got this strange issue with Entity Framework 5 where I have a navigation property in one of my entities that I would like to set to `null`. But for some reason the property only gets cleared the second time I call this property:

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    var vehicle = db.Vehicles.Single(v => v.Id == vehicleId);

    // After this call, ParkingBay is still set.
    vehicle.ParkingBay = null;

    // Only after this call, ParkingBay becomes null.
    vehicle.ParkingBay = null;

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The `Vehicle` class that Entity Framework generates looks like this:

```
public partial class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual ParkingBay ParkingBay { get; set; }
}
```

This code isn't very exiting, and at runtime Entity Framework generates proxy classes for both `Vehicle` and `ParkingBay`, but I can't understand what happens inside that `ParkingBay` property that fails to clear the property on the first call.

Between `Vehicle` and `ParkingBay` is a normal Foreign Key relationship in SQL Server. Nothing special here.

**UPDATE**

The `ParkingBay` looks like this:

```
public partial class ParkingBay
{
    public ParkingBay()
    {
        this.Vehicles = new HashSet<Vehicle>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}
```

What's going on here? Can someone enlighten me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Every property in Vehicle should be virtual for Proxies to work. Also, your class is listed as partial, so what are the other parts of your class like?

Comment: @hjb417: Apparently not, since that code is generated for me by Entity Framework itself.

Comment: You can modify the TT file so that it does this. It has some method in it that sets stuff like, the type of collection to use and how to make the properties. The default collection is HashSet but I had to change it to ICollection so it could work with proxies. For now, why don't you try manually editing the Vehicle class so that every property is virtual and make sure the ProxyCreationEnabled is set to true.

Comment: One more thing, can you also show the ParkingBay class.

Comment: In fact, even the second call ` = null` shouldn't "really" set it to `null`. Did you inspect the property in the debugger between these calls?

Comment: @GertArnold: Both while debugging and without. Effect is the same.

Comment: Surprising. I would expect the property not to get loaded by the first `null` assignment (neither by the second). Can you check that by looking at SQL statements?

Comment: Anyway, I put in answer what I'm pretty sure is going on here.

Comment: Try to do it this way: db.Entry(vehicle).Reference(v => v.ParkingBay).CurrentValue = null;

Comment: @GertArnold: You are right, the property doesn't get loaded on the first `null` assignment, but it (of course) gets loaded when I inspect it in the debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the query statement (`db.Vehicles.Single ...`) the property *is* null, because you don't load it. Assigning another value to it doesn't trigger a lazy load, so nothing changes here.

Only when the property is actually loaded an assignment (*any* assignment, also replacing it by another object) will have an effect. If the property isn't loaded, the change tracker has nothing to track.

The property can get loaded by including it in the query

```
db.Vehicles.Include(v => v.ParkingBay)...
```

or by addressing it later in the code, e.g.

```
var pb = vehicle.ParkingBay; // triggers lazy loading.
```

or by inspecting it in the debugger (watch or quickview), which also trigger lazy loading.

`Include` is the recommended approach if you intend to apply any changes to navigation properties themselves.

As commented below, a better performing way to clear a reference navigation property is to expose the primitive foreign key value in the model and set it to `null`. In your case, this would be something like `int? ParkingBayId`. This pattern is know as *foreign key associations*, as opposed to *independent associations*, when only the reference property is present.

Comment: I don't agree with the recommendation for Include. I think that can be avoided by using foreign key properties, and you can then set the value to null without having to touch the navigation object. See --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Comment: Gert, your advice does work, but I don't understand why this should be needed, especially since the the MSDN docs that @hjb417 is refering to, explicitly states that this works with EF5.

Comment: I think this is most likely a bug in EF5 because in both calls, the getter is never explicitly accessed, only the setter. But I think if your goal is to simply break an association between two entities, the most efficient way is to expose a foreign key property for ParkingBay (e.x.: public virtual int? ParkingBayId) on Vehicle that you can set to null. To set it to null on the navigation property, you'll need to bring in more data than you need (E.x.: You'll make SQL join in data from another table when you don't need any of it's data).

Comment: @hjb417 I agree. The `Include` would be recommended for collection properties, if you want to modify the associations through the parent.

Comment: Gert, we had performance problems with Includes and ended up using lazy loading. We had such a deep object graph and were navigating down so many levels that the Include caused EF to generate SQL that caused massive resultset to be returned and this is because the resultset contains duplicate data because it's a cartesian product. This is an inefficiency of EF include, they should have returned the Include's as extra resultsets and use the IDataReader.NextResult to get that data.

Comment: So with that said, we ended up using LazyLoading to get the collections on demand. There are downsides to that though becayse all the data is not retrieved at once so you can have race conditions where data is deleted/modified between calls. You can fix that problem by using the TransactionScope but that's overkill.

Comment: @hjb417 I can imagine that. Includes blow up the SQL result set in width and (when they are 1-n) in length. generally, I don't think there should be more than 3 or 4 includes in a statement (depending on the width of the records and the cardinality of the associations). Loading on demand, or loading in a few separate queries can be much faster. BTW, I edited the answer following your remarks.

Comment: @Steven, Your're right, but the problem STILL persists in .NET4.5/EF6. Why do MS explicitly state that it should work in EF5+ when it doesn't?...

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to load Property before setting it to `null`. I agree with Gert Arnold's answer, just wanted to add more alternatives to do it:

```
db.Entry(vehicle).Reference(c => c.ParkingBay).Load();
vehicle.ParkingBay = null;
```

OR

```
db.Entry(vehicle).Reference(v => v.ParkingBay).CurrentValue = null;
```

[MSDN Relationships and Navigation Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)

Comment: The MSDN documentation states "Starting with the Entity Framework 5.0, that is based on .NET 4.5, you can set the relationship to null without loading the related end.", but I'm using .NET 4.5 and Entity Framework 5. So I would expect this to work without `ParkingBay` to be loaded.

Comment: Fair enough, I understood that sentence wrongly at first place.

Comment: When using a repository this would require you to expose EF/5/6 specific code .. It wasn't needed with ObjectContext, and shouldn't be needed with dbContext + proxies... any other fixes to make this work automagically?