# How to properly Delete fields of an Entity?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am having trouble when trying to delete a field of an Entity using Entity Framework (version 6.1.3).

Let's say I have two Entities: `Person` and `Work`.
I can change the work of a person without any issue, but when I try to express that the person is unemployed it does not work properly:

```
 person.Work = null;
 db.SaveChanges();
```

After running this code the person still will have the previous work, but if I use the debugger and check the `Work` property of `person` before running 
`person.Work = null;`, everything will behave as expected.

Can someone please explain why reading the value first makes the code work properly and how to correctly delete the field?

```
 var work = person.Work; \\ with this line here everything works as expected
 person.Work = null;
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I will say that it is not exactly the same issue but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557699/entity-framework-5-does-not-clear-navigation-property answer definitely helps. I am doing now `db.Entry(person).Reference(x => x.Work ).CurrentValue = null;` that works like a charm.

Comment: see the answers below. Your problem is that EF does not recognize that you have changed Work property of the person. Usually (always) is because EF could not build a proxy for person because you did not mark the property Work as virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that are contributing to your issue:

1. Entity Framework determines what needs to updated during `SaveChanges` by [tracking changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205) to property values.
2. You probably have [lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazy) enabled (both in general and for the `Work` property), which means that if the `person` has an associated `Work`, that associated entity doesn't get loaded until the first time you access that property.

Putting those together, when you set `person.Work = null` without accessing `person.Work` (which would trigger a load), the context thinks nothing has changed. But if you [load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazy) the property first, setting the property to null tells EF to remove that association. **Edit:** According to [the page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) that [octavioccl linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31172408/4812586), this is true for .NET 4.0., but for .NET 4.5+ (and EF 5+), loading first is unneeded.

**Possible solutions**

1. If you want to remove the association without loading the related entity, you'll need to add a foreign key property to your `Person` entity, then you can set that to null instead of setting the navigation property to null. For example:

   ```
   public class Person
   {
       // other properties...
       public int? WorkId { get; set; }
       public virtual Work { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   ```
   person.WorkId = null;
   db.SaveChanges();
   ```
2. [octavioccl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31172408/4812586) quoted another option:

   > `context.Entry(person).Reference(p => p.Work).CurrentValue = null;`

Comment: It's possible a solution without using the foreign key property?

Comment: It was not null before setting the property to `person.Work = null`. I would expect entity framework to be able to detect the change anyways without the need of a foreign key property. It's possible to flag the entity as modified or something?

Comment: @kamayd: sorry that null part was explained poorly -- octavioccl's edited answer has a better explanation. Essentially, the navigation property needs to be loaded first. Let me edit that as well.

Comment: @kamayd: as for another solution see octavioccl's answer

Answer (score 0):

From this [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx):

> To delete the relationship, set the navigation property to `null`. If
>   you are working with the Entity Framework that is based on .NET 4.0,
>   then the related end needs to be loaded before you set it to `null`. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> context.Entry(person).Reference(p => p.Work).Load();
> person.Work = null;
> ```
>
> Starting with the Entity Framework 5.0, that is based on .NET 4.5, you
>   can set the relationship to null without loading the related end. You
>   can also set the current value to `null` using the following method:
>
> ```
> context.Entry(person).Reference(p => p.Work).CurrentValue = null;
> ```